# Ubuntu Server Management - How do I stop hard drive space from creeping up over time?

Tags: server, hard-drive, application-development

I have been using ubuntu servers (not the full desktop version) for the last 5 years, I have consistently had the same issue with hard drive space creeping up over time.

I use AWS CloudWatch to notify me if a server crosses 80% hard drive space consumption, when they do, in general, I have followed the following steps in order to trim down my footprint.

Unfortunately though even after doing these steps it doesn't always bring the hard drive space under 80% and **I end up having to increase my hard drive space about every 4-5 months**. I mainly develop using two programming languages and deploy REST API's in Ruby and NodeJS.

---

- On servers running NodeJS, we use PM2 for application management, and proxy pass NGINX traffic to ExpressJS
- On servers running Ruby, we use passenger + NGINX
- On every server I have logging enabled in my REST API's, and I rotate (delete) my logs automatically after moving them off the server

---

*To trim down my memory footprint I do the following:*

Step 1) keep my system updated

`sudo apt update`

Step 2) *sometimes* running upgrade, it can be scary to upgrade to a new major ubuntu version if you are not prepared to

`sudo apt upgrade`

Step 3) cleaning out apt package cache

`sudo apt clean`

Step 4) removing old kernals

`sudo apt autoremove --purge`

---

I need some way of being able to see what part of my OS creeps up in hard drive consumption over time, I have ran different scripts that tell me how large folders are etc, but I still haven't found any conclusive solutions or evidences of the problem, ubuntu with my understanding just keeps creeping on memory.

Are there any solutions that others have to my problem?

Here is a graphic for the last three months of all the ubuntu servers in my cloud environment, sometimes there are jumps - but they are also steadily increasing little by little
[image]

Comment: @Rinzwind the unfortunate thing is that databases in my cloud environment are stored on separate servers than application servers. And some of the servers pictured havent had any code updates in months so no files have changed due to something i've knowingly done...

Comment: @Jeff - hard drive memory, it looks like the other person deleted their comment - they said that hard drive memory increases from databases and files added

Comment: If your data usage is slowly increasing, I would review applications that may collect data and disable data collection, whenever possible. For instance, you can disable storing of cookies in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: @Jeff the only client installed applications would be NGINX (outputs http traffic logging, it rotates its logs), AWS Code Deploy Agent <-- strong candidate for bloating it updates itself, NodeJS, Yarn, and Ruby. other than that i cant think of any applications collecting data, these are the only installed apps. My apps that i have written dont. This is Ubuntu Server OS - so no firefox

Comment: Is it likely that storing the data from these apps to an external hard drive would help? Maybe if you forced these apps to save to hard drive.

Comment: I would if i knew what app(s) were causing any bloating

Comment: You just told me which ones were causing bloating: NGINX is logging and rotating logs to another location, which causes an excessive amount of data stored in that directory. If you told it to store logs and such to an external hard drive.........

Comment: I can't access chat, otherwise, I would agree. If you want, you can contact me at lalldredge7622@uinta1.org

That is my email

Comment: @Jeff logging doesnt necessarily equate to bloating if the application deletes (rotates) logs after X number of days
we do copy over some logs to AWS S3 (essentially an external hard drive for long term storage) before the system deletes them

Comment: Finding out where your disk space has gone is most easily done from the command line. Read `man du df find`.